# DNAT forwarding for FTP: No route to host

Tags: iptables, routing, ftp

I have a single public IP for multiple VM, i need forward multiple ports for FTP service, i write these lines:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20:21 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.110:20-21
```

or

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 20:21 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.110
```

But i have always the same error when i connect with FTP client: no route to host

Comment: unless there is a specific FTP conntrack module for iptables, your gonna have issues with ftp cuz of the way active/passive work they are a pain to fw/route/masq..... try scp or rsync over ssh... not an answer cuz i dont know how to make ftp work in this situation,... just know not to use it

Comment: I have loaded `nf_nat_ftp` and `nf_conntrack_ftp` modules but not work, i have modify the rules: `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 20 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.110:20`and `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.4.110:21`. `FORWARD`and `OUTPUT` is accept by default in all traffic